# What is <Integer> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, integer

I've seen a lot of code portions that have something like:

```
return callback ( new someFunction <Integer>() {
  //something
});
```

But I don't know what is it.

Can you tell me what is the name of `<type>` and how to use it?

Comment: Read about [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: I guess you meant `Integer` instead of `integer`. `Integer` is a class, `int` is a primitive type.

Comment: Are you sure this is Java, that might be an anonymous class definition (but it doesn't look right)... did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: No, Java, I'm newbie in this language, sorry

Comment: This ain't Java. I'm sorry.

Comment: That is *invalid* Java [7] code (it is also not valid JavaScript). Perhaps you meant `new SomeType<Integer>() { .. }` .. in which case "see generics". Anyway, make sure posted code is either *valid* or the question is about the validity of such code ..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a particular programming problem, instead it is asking for basic information that is widely found in API documentation online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an [anonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) class, the syntax might seems a little strange if you're new to the language.

The first "strange" part is the `<Integer>` [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), that specifies the class offers some methods that can take (and possibly return) `any Object` type. By specifying `<Integer>` you will get a compiler error if you try and pass some other type (you're telling the compiler additional type information).

The second "strange" part is the [anonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) class which is defined in-line; `someFunction` must be the name of the "superclass" (or interface) you are creating there.

Here is a somewhat contrived (but complete) example,

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {
  public T logIt(T in);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SomeInterface<Integer> si = (new SomeInterface<Integer>() {
    public Integer logIt(Integer in) {
      System.out.println("in logIt " + in);
      return in;
    }
  });
  System.out.println(si.logIt(100));
}
```

Outputs

```
in logIt 100
100
```

Comment: "It is an anonymous generic class" The anonymous class is not generic.